Getting an error saying assessment must be an instance
In my assessment section model, I have defined a foreign key like this:
assessment_id = models.ForeignKey(to=Assessment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
related_name='section_assessment_mapping', null=False, blank=False,
    help_text="The assessment associated with this section.")

This points to the assessment model's ID which is the primary key.
in assessment section serializer, I have defined the assessment id like this:
   assessment_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=True)
This is the create method of the serializer:
def create(self, validated_data):
  print('validdata',validated_data)
  print(validated_data.get('assessment_id'))
  section_obj = 
    AssessmentSection.objects.create_with_defaults(**validated_data)
        return section_obj

And this is the create API for assessment section:
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        serializer = AssessmentSectionSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except ValidationError as e:
        service_logger.error(str(e))
        return Response({'error': True, 'message': e.args[0]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except Exception as e:
        service_logger.error(str(e))
        raise StandardizedException(error_status=True, error_obj=e, status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


Now when I hit the API with payload containing assessment_id, which has some valid assessment ID that is present in the DB, it gives this error:
Cannot assign \"UUID('7025deca-afb8-4ad3-93b8-6035599bcf6e')\": \"AssessmentSection.assessment_id\" must be a \"Assessment\" instance."
}

I have tried several approaches, but they are not working. I just need to store the assessment id in the table with section info.
Tried using source=assesment.id in the serializer field but didn't work.

Rename the ForeignKey to assessment:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Assessment,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='section_assessment_mapping',
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text='The assessment associated with this section.',
    )
A ForeignKey [Django-doc] in Django revers to the object it refers to, and you can access a fieldname_id field for the field in the target model it uses.
See furthermore this article I wrote about this [django-antipatterns].

tried this but still the same error is there.

@darshan: you should not rename the assessment_id of the data, so not in the serializer, only in the model.

yes i did that.
model:assessment = models.ForeignKey(to=Assessment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,                                      related_name='section_assessment_mapping',
help_text="The assessment associated with this section.")
serializer:    assessment_id = serializers.UUIDField(required=True)
now im getting this error:{
"error": true,
"message": {
"assessment": [
"This field is required."
]
}
}

@darshan: specify 'assessment' in the excluded fields of the serializer.

Hi, thanks it has been fixed. What i did was just fetch the assessment object and assigned its ID to assessment_id of the request body. Thanks for your help.
